# wso2 - Verification Failed - App with identifier.com.myapp. and version 1.0 already exists

Tags: wso2

I'm confused. I published an app. Now I have a new version, I retired the old version. However when I try to update to the new version and publish in the store I'm unable to.

It seems very much like this issue?

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-60

How do I patch or fix this issue?

Is it possible to delete the app from the store?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed and verified in 1.0 RC3. So is not the case. Does it throw any errors in the console?